# Convert a .dmp Database (made with EXP) to an unique .sql file (with Oracle 12.2.0)

Tags: oracle, dmp

I need to convert a .dmp database file to an unique .sql file.
I have installed Oracle 12.2.0.
I am using Windows 10.

How can i do it?

Thank you so much

Comment: .dmp (title) or .bmp (body)? What tool was the file created with?

Comment: @codo - Maybe it's a screenshot of a database model

Comment: @jorge It is .dmp

Answer (score 0):

Be it a datapump dump or a dump exported with conventional export: both tools create files in a proprietary format, and you can't convert them to text.

Why would you want to do that? If you want to recreate the schema with all the data in it just import the dump with impdp (datapump) or imp (conventional) and you have the schema.

If you want to know a certain structure of an object (e.g. a view) you could import only that object.

just run impdp help=Y (datapump) or imp help=Y (conventional) to see how to do that.

If you really want a readable file of your database then have a look at Oracle SQL*Developer which supports unloading tables into insert statements and the like and exporting DDL Statements of certain objects into text format.

cheers

Comment: The .dmp that i have was made with "exp" and not with "expdp", so it is impossible to do a impdp importation. The problem that i have is that i don't have sufficients privileges (ORA-1031 error) to do an importation with "imp". So, my idea is to get an unique SQL file from the given .DMP (made with EXP) and the try to do the importation from SQL Developer. The given .DMP is the only one that i could have (work reasons). So your answer is not usefull for my question.

Comment: And what makes you think that the ORA-1031 will go away when you try to execute your SQL Statements when issuing the DDL Statement from another tool? Because that is exactly what IMP would do as well - issue a DDL statement which it extracted from your dump file - which will fail because obviously your target schema misses privileges.